# Is it possible a V4L2 driver for with UART communication?

Tags: linux-device-driver, uart, v4l2

I would like to develop a kernel driver for a camera that uses UART as communication protocol for control. Is it actually possible? Because searching on the internet I didn't find a real answer.

And if yes, how?

I already developed a couple of kernel drivers (for 5.10.x) for two different image sensors within the V4L2 framework, but both were using I2C as communication protocol to control the sensor.

Comment: **1.** Yes, it's possible. **2.** Read documentation on both hardware and Linux kernel development, see what others already made, etc...

Comment: @0andriy thank you for the response. I actually read the documentation about the V4L2 framework and searched in the kernel, but there are no implementations of such use case. Do you have any suggestion where to find such an example?